# Android fragment - different layout into fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to develop an application compatible with smartphones (one pane layout) and tablets (two panes layout). My app is displayed as shown below:

[image: fragment]
<sub>(source: [android10.org](http://android10.org/images/stories/develoment_1/working_with_fragments_android10_02.png))</sub>

I used the example available in [Google developers website](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

The example works fine. But for my app, I need to use different layout in the `WebView fragment`. Each element selected in `ListView fragment` shows a specific layout into the right fragment.

This is my code called when an element is clicked :

```
public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the
    // HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    BodyFragment articleFrag = (BodyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.body_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and
        // must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected
        // article
        BodyFragment newFragment = new BodyFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(BodyFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this
        // fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can
        // navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

How can I should make it? I thought to replace dynamically the layout into the fragment, but it is not possible.

Is anybody has a solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Simply keep only one Fragment for the webview just on the listfragment click (position) call what u want to view

Comment: My code is visible above. I don't know where I can set the layout to use into my fragment :(